# Catching exception 'TimeoutError'

Tags: python-3.x

I can't seem to catching this TimeoutError exception. The other topics found on this are suggesting using "except TimeoutError" for Python 3, but it's still throwing an error. The error log is below.

I have also tried to import the *requests* module which didn't make any difference.  Assuming this is an easy fix, I just can't figure it out.  How can I fix it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 83, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 345, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 844, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 284, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x106f3dd68>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 649, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 376, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.spotify.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/artists/090VebphoycdEyH165iMqc (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x106f3dd68>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "populate2.py", line 130, in <module>
    r = s.get_artist(a['uri'])
  File "/Users/tapoffice/Google Drive/OSCAR SIDEBO/Programming/Python/Spotify/spotify_handler.py", line 44, in get_artist
    search = self.spotifyHandler.artist(uri)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 244, in artist
    return self._get('artists/' + trid)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 146, in _get
    return self._internal_call('GET', url, payload, kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 108, in _internal_call
    r = self._session.request(method, url, headers=headers, proxies=self.proxies, **args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 487, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.spotify.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/artists/090VebphoycdEyH165iMqc (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x106f3dd68>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out',))
```

Here's the actual script running. Basically, it iterates over a list requested from a database and performs an API requests to collect information that then gets added back into the database.  I realize the root of this issue it exceeding the rate limits of the API, so the solution would be to allow the script to sleep for 1 minute before continuing. I don't want to use "except Exception" since I could be missing other errors.  The script below doesn't catch the TimeoutError which is what I don't understand.

```python
for a in [x for x in songs.get('*')]:
    try:
        r = s.get_track(a['uri'])
        pop = r['popularity']
        songupdates.add_row(['song_id', 'popularity'], [str(a['id']), str(pop)])

    except TimeoutError:
        print("TimeoutError, sleeping 1 minute.")
        time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: better you drop your code here, based on the log seems its throwing another error 'MaxRetryError' while you are handling the 'TimeoutError'

Comment: Maybe MaxRetryError is the consequence of an inexpected behaviour that raise TimeoutError. except TimeoutError works fine. I would suggest handling every exception and log it with logging with:
try:
    do_your_task()
except exception:
    logger.error("Something went bad", exc_info=True)

Comment: @KiruparanBalachandran just edited my post and added the code from script.

Comment: @FedericoRubbi following your suggestion, will I see what error is causing the script to break in the first place?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: I've encountered the same issue in jupyter notebook. Catching only the initial TimeoutException or the final ConnectionError still causes an exception raise in a try block. 

catching all `except Exception as e` is probably the way to go

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comment below your post, debugging could be useful.

In my opinion, the exception occurs in the list comprehension `[x for x in songs.get('*')]` (I assume songs.get() make some request), outside the `try` block and that's the reason you can't handle it.

The output of this code may be helpful:

```py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('my_app')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('my_app.log')
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

try:
    logger.info('Starting for-loop')
    for a in songs.get('*'):
        logger.info('Getting song track')
        r = s.get_track(a['uri'])
        pop= r['popularity']
        logger.info('Adding a row')
        songupdates.add_row(['song_id','popularity'],[str(a['id']),str(pop)])
except Exception:
    logger.error('An error occurred', exc_info=True)
```

If the last information message of the logger is 'Starting the for-loop', there are two possibilities: the request is invalid (not probable, I guess) or there is effectively need to slow down the code with time.sleep() or, if possible, incrementing the timeout, passing the keyworded argument somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i.e. looping over a list and requesting data for each entry of the list. This would lead to the error described in the question. I was able to resolve the issue by this except statement:

```
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as err:
    print(err)
```

Some more information: the other three exceptions mentioned in the question are located in `requests` or `urllib3`, respectively:

- urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError
- urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError
- requests.exceptions.Timeout